# NSSM couldn't set startup parameters for the service!deleting the service

Tags: nssm

The operating system is Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise 64-bit.When I was doing the following configuration,error appears like the following picture.It's a python service.

**Error**

[image: error.png]

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same issue and running the command prompt as Administrator fixed it for me.